# Want to add swap partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu-15.10

I wanted to add swap partition in my Ubuntu 15.10
Using dual boot with windows XP,
& Building Cyanogenmod 13 with Linux but always getting error as following,

```
make:*fork:*Cannot allocate memory
```

which is related to RAM
I have searched & found that need to add swap memory in my Ubuntu,
some one is suggested is you need at least 4GB RAM (I have) + 4GB swap partition to continue build.
[about my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NK2C7.png)
while checked & found that there is already have swap partition or anything else like attached picture,
[swap partition details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNrfB.png)
but now confused that what can help me to continue my build 
does anyone have solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Just continue doing what you started make swap partition or a file.
On the picture you already have a swap file, but it's a bit small for your task (256M) just add another one there could be many.

if you are not very familiar with partitioning - making swap file will be less dangerous. You could make one more swap file like this

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/path_to_your_swap_file_to_be/swap_file bs=1M count=1024` 
this will create 1 gig file, if you need 4gigs and your system support so much  use 4M blocks or 4096 count.

`sudo mkswap /path_to_your_swap_file_to_be/swap_file`
this will place swap header into file

`sudo swapon /path_to_your_swap_file_to_be/swap_file`
this will add the file to a swap space

`free- m`
now you should see your swap memory pool extended

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
/path_to_your_swap_file_to_be/swap_file swap swap defaults 0 0
```

to file */etc/fstab* too. Without this, your swap file will disappear after reboot.

Comment: If I’m understanding you correctly, this needs to be done in _addition_ to the previous answer, not as a _substitute_ for it. If so, this would be better addressed as a comment—but, at minimum, should refer back to that answer. Otherwise, each answer is expected to be a self-contained solution to the original question.

Comment: Yes, this is addition to Konstantin Ivanov recipe.